# WPF trigger from Settings.settings variable

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, settings

I added `bool` variable into my `Settings.settings` file to store user configuration preferences:

[image]

And in code behind i am changing this this way:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.autoCheckForUpdates = true;
```

Is it possible to add this `bool` var to my control `trigger` using `XAML` ?

Comment: I would recommend using a model in between, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648832/viewmodels-in-mvc-mvvm-seperation-of-layers-best-practices

Comment: Do you mean to use binding object with properties ?

Comment: Yes, create a `viewmodel` for your `xaml-view`, you can set the `BindingContext` from it's "code-behind". If your view interacts with your viewmodel, you can set your settings though that. It seems ike more effort but in the long run it is better to maintain. I could fix you an example if you like

Comment: Yes i will glad to see example, BTW i need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataTrigger shown below works. You don't need a view model with property change notification, since the `Settings` class already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:YourAppNamespace.Properties"
...

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(properties:Settings.Default).autoCheckForUpdates}"
             Value="True">
    <Setter .../>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Can i have this example inside MenuItem please ?

Comment: In which MenuItem? You haven't shown any in your question. Just add this DataTrigger to the Triggers collection of a Style.

Comment: Will it save the setting as well?

Comment: @Stefan Why would it? It doesn't even change a setting. OP is asking about a trigger, not a TwoWay binding to a setting.

Comment: I got this error: XamlParseException: Type reference cannot find type named '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}Properties.Settings'.

Comment: You need to declare the Properties namespace in XAML, like `xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:YourAppNamespace.Properties"`

Answer (score 1):

As promised, the overkill version, which doesn't makes sense for your question but might help you out in another way: a simple viewmodel with INotifyPropertyChanged.
I wil extend the example with some binding.

Your viewmodel:

```
public class SettingsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _autoUpdate;
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
        //set initial value
        _autoUpdate = Properties.Settings.Default.autoCheckForUpdates;
    }

    public bool AutoCheckForUpdates 
    {
        get { return _autoUpdate; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _autoUpdate) return;
            _autoUpdate= value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.autoCheckForUpdates = value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //the INotifyPropertyChanged stuff
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In the code behind of your XAML:

```
public SettingsWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new SettingsViewModel();
}
```

Now, in your XAML, you can bind to this property, through a textbox for example:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding AutoCheckForUpdates}"/>
```