# Binding to multiple properties is Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindingsource

I'm trying to figure out how to bind a ListView to two or more objects in Xamarin forms...

I want to keep the objects separate because they both correspond to different tables in a database. Is it wrong of me to want to keep them separate?

Comment: Hi, please show some code. Furthermore, please try to google a bit about the MVVM pattern. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648832/viewmodels-in-mvc-mvvm-seperation-of-layers-best-practices/23649191#23649191

Comment: you cannot do this you need to create a custom class and have all the data there

Comment: By 2 objects you mean to different List of items or 2 different properties?

Comment: @Woj I meant 2 different Lists of items

Comment: @G.hakim Hmmm, That's what I thought I might need to do...

I'll look in MVVM pettern

Comment: @RobotMan do you want those 2 lists to display in the same time or one or the other?

Comment: @Woj I wanted to be able to bind a listView to elements from a choice of two or more lists... It sounds as though I need to creates a new list with both sets of data inside