# Net Core: Create Response Class for Each API Action?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, request-response

Our software architect is mandating all API Actions have their own Response Class, since every Response can be slightly difference.  So we basically wrap the Product DTO in a Base Response class, and slightly customize if needed. Is this good architectural practice? I started programming and it Seems kind of repetitive. Also, what is a nicer optimal alternative for this?

**Product Class:**

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public int ProductId { get; set;},
    public string ProductName { get; set;},
    public string ProductDescription { get; set;},
    public float SalesAmount { get; set;}
}
```

**BaseResponse:**

```
public class BaseResponse<T>
{
    [Required, ValidateObject]
    public T Body { get; set; }
    public bool HasError { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

**Individual Response:**

```
public class CreateProductResponse : BaseResponse<ProductDto>
{
}

public class DeleteProductResponse : BaseResponse<int>
{
}

public class GetAllProductResponse : BaseResponse<IEnumerable<ProductDto>>
{
    public int Count { get; set;};
}

public class GetProductResponse : BaseResponse<ProductDto>
{
}

public class UpdateProductResponse : BaseResponse<ProductDto>
{
    public date DateUpdate { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Main developer's task is to make a complex problem simple and more understandable, if repetition in code helps it, I believe that it's not bad. In the case you have mentioned, I think, that is not a repetition, it is kind of `inheritance` with `Generic type` which is acceptable.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648832/viewmodels-in-mvc-mvvm-separation-of-layers-best-practices

Comment: You (and the architect) might be interested in GraphQL instead of building your own protocol.

Comment: Hi @huysentruitw I read about graphql, in which sense would this help? still need to create different models for response types, what is recommended solution, feel free to place in answer, thanks-

Comment: Yes, you'll need different models, but you'll no longer have to wrap them inside a generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least with a current example, I would say it's a bit overthinking.
There are many derived classes who have no additional its own properties. Probably in the future, the same pattern will stay on.

A better solution would be to make BaseResponse as an interface for better extensibility for implementing same properties of several different interfaces.
Below it's more detailed information.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/382882/why-inherit-a-class-and-not-add-properties

Answer (score 0):

it's difficult to say good/bad architectural practice by seeing this piece of code. in our case, we use the below the pattern and find it reasonable

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public bool HasError { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}   


public class CreateProductResponse : BaseResponse
{
 ---
}

public class CreateProductDetailResponse : CreateProductResponse
{
 ---
}
```